# Can I use the preposition "for" with the meaning of support or agreement in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, semantics

The sentence is as below,

*The discovery is being resisted by many people for exploiting fetal tissue.*

It seems more appropriate to interpret it as below,
"*exploiting fetal tissue*" is the reason of "*many people resist the discovery*"

My questions is, is it able to use the preposition "for" for agreement and interpret it as below,
"*many people who agree with exploiting fetal tissue*" resisted the discovery.
\

Is it grammatically and semantically possible?
Thank you for your kindness in advance.

//

add-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//

+the discovery : a possible treatment for strokes and degenerative diseases by the transplantation of human fetal tissue into the brain to repair damage.

//

The discovery is being resisted by many people for exploiting fetal tissue.

The discovery is being resisted by many people for excluding fetal tissue.

which is right?

Answer (score 3):

The sentence means *The discovery is being resisted by many people **because it involves** exploiting fetal tissue.*

It's true that *for* can mean *in favour of*, but the interpretation 'resisted by people who are in favour of exploiting fetal tissue' is very unlikely. In any case, it doesn't make sense; why would such people object to a procedure which uses fetal tissue?

Comment: I also think the interpretation with 'in favor of' is unnatural. Then how about the sentence "*The discovery is being resisted by many people for excluding fetal tissue.*"??

Comment: I've already said that that sentence is acceptable in the sense I gave.

Comment: Can you check the sentence again? // The first sentence is “*The discovery is being resisted by many people for exploiting fetal tissue.*” and the second is “*The discovery is being resisted by many people for excluding fetal tissue.*”

Comment: exploit / exclude

Comment: People who are for excluding fetal tissue can resist the discovery, can’t they?

Comment: Of course I respect native English user’s intuition and I will convey this messages to my student.

Comment: Oh, I beg your pardon. I didn't notice that you had changed a word in the sentence. I still think that _resisted for [doing something]_ would be understood to mean _resisted because it [does something]_. If the other sense was intended, we would say _resisted by many people **who are** for..._ or, more likely, _who are in favour of..._

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer would be so much helpful to explain this issue to my students.